# Property that have interface is undefined?

Tags: angular

I have two interfaces:

customer.interface.ts

```
export interface Customer{
  name?:string;
  customerinfo?:CustomerInfo;
}
```

customerinfo.interface.ts

```
export interface CustomerInfo{
  code?:number;
}
```

In html i have this:

```
<input [ngModel]="customer.customerinfo.code">
```

Problem is that i get an error that customerinfo is undefined. Any suggestion? 
If i added that customerinfo is optional why do i have this problem?

Comment: Just because the type defines that property doesn't mean an actual object has it. Show us where customer is coming from.

Comment: @IngoBurk sometimes i will not have it in response and sometimes i will..i mean sometimes API will return information about customerinfo and sometimes not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues first of all, it should be **`[(ngModel)]`** with safe navigation operator

```
<input [(ngModel)]="customer?.customerinfo?.code">
```

also you need to initialize the object customer in your component.

```
customer : Customer = {};
```

**EDIT**

Since you are getting the data from API, sometimes the cusotmer will be undefined since it returns the value asynchronously, use safe-navigation operator as below

```
<input [(ngModel)]="customer?.customerinfo?.code">
```

Comment: customer is type of Customer(interface)

Comment: Whether to use two way binding depends on the context, so saying it is wrong is in fact wrong. And initializing the object like this will still cause errors.

Comment: @uzhas its just you need to initialize whatever the type is

Comment: @IngoBürk not sure what you are refering to

Comment: @Sajeetharan i want to use interface to avoid this ? in my html...thats the only reason. And if i use interface why do i need = {} ?